# Why does the base class need a default constructor?

Tags: c++

Consider this code:

```cpp
#include <string>

struct Float {
    float f;
    Float(float f) : f(f) {}
};

struct FloatOrString : Float {
    using Float::Float;
    std::string s;
    FloatOrString(std::string s) : s(s) {}
};


int main() {
    FloatOrString f1(1.2);
    FloatOrString f2("hello");
}
```

I get the error:

> error: constructor for 'FloatOrString' must explicitly initialize the base class 'Float' which does not have a default constructor

Why do I need a default constructor in the base class? How can I get round having to provide one?

Comment: Derived classes contain a base class. That base class must be constructed. Use the member initializer list to construct it.

Comment: You're using the default constructor here: `FloatOrString(std::string s) : s(s) {}`.  If you want to use a different constructor, you need to specify it: `FloatOrString(std::string s) : Float{1.0}, s{std::move(s)} {}`.

Comment: Side note: Looks like you might be trying to reinvent [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant). But if so, why use inheritance?

Comment: You might want to ask a question about [the problem that lead you to this as a solution](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/1145533) because you may be digging yourself a hole. It's too late to repurpose or expand the scope of this question (it has a correct answer) so it would have to be a new question.

Comment: Your implementation of the constructor of `FloatOrString` does not explicitly initialise the base.  The base must be initialised and, in your case of writing a derived class constructor that does not initialise the base, the default constructor of the base is used, so must be defined.   One way to avoid is to initialise all bases explicitly e.g. `FloatOrString(std::string s) : Float(std::atof(s)), s(s) {}`   (`std::atof()` is declared in `<cstdlib>`).

Answer (score 9):

`FloatOrString` is *not* an "either-or" type. As you've written it, the class `FloatOrString` demands *both* a `float f` and a `std::string s`. So you need to call the parent constructor because you have to supply a value for the base class field `float f`, since your `FloatOrString` object must be a valid `Float` object (that's called the Liskov substitution principle).

If you want an "either-or" design, use [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) instead, so there's no need to write your own class for it.

Answer (score 1):

> Why do I need a default constructor in the base class?

When you create an instance of `FloatOrString` with a string, the compiler doesn't know how to initialise the `Float` <s>part</s> subobject of `FloatOrString` because `Float` does not have a default constructor. You can get around this by providing a default constructor for `Float`,

> How can I get round having to provide one?

You can explicitly initializing the `Float` part in the `FloatOrString` constructor like this:

```
FloatOrString(std::string s) : Float(0), s(s) {}
```

But - it looks bad, I would expect base class to be initialized with `std::stof(s)`, but `s` in your code example might be non - float.

Generally, I would suggest using `std::variant` (or union - variant requires c++17) in this case:

```
using FloatOrString = std::variant<float, std::string>;
```

Sample code: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8f931e32ef938d79

```
#include <variant>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    using FloatOrString = std::variant<float, std::string>;
    
    FloatOrString f1{1.2f};
    FloatOrString f2{"hello"};
    
    if (std::holds_alternative<float>(f1)) {
        std::cout << "It's a float: " << std::get<float>(f1) << '\n';
    }
    
    // Switching to string
    f1 = "hello";
    if (std::holds_alternative<std::string>(f1)) {
        std::cout << "It's a string: " << std::get<std::string>(f1) << '\n';
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a nitpick: what you call a "part" is formally called a _subobject_ in the C++ standard, as mentioned in [`intro.object/2`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/intro.object#2) and explained in great detail somewhere in [`class.derived`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/class.derived).